# Firefox: Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

Tags: firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate

**Firefox 28.0 (latest version)**

I got error when i want open my site with SSL (https) on firefox, it's ok with chrome, but can't open with FireFox:

> SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
>   Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long

is it problem with SSL certificate? or what? or it's just FF problem?

Comment: Can you provide a packet capture of the connection (tcpdump, wireshark - but with the raw packets not just the text dump) or give the URL so one can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich , here is: https://www.linkinpark-fans.com and i don't how to provie a packet capture of the connection. thanks

Comment: I don't get this error with firefox, but I see that the site is misconfigured: it sends not only the leaf certificate and the intermediate certificates but also the root certificate, e.g. the one which is shipped with the browser already. Searching for the error message you report shows, that it can happen together with misconfigured certificate chains.